# html5 link in jquery script

Tags: jquery, html

I need to trasform this lines of jquery script

```
if (settings.explicitConsent) {
        html += scriptsDisclosure + settings.explicitCookieDeletionWarning;
        html += settings.explicitFindOutMore + '<a style="color:' + settings.linkColor + ';font-weight:bold;';
        html += 'font-family:' + settings.fontFamily + ';font-size:' + settings.fontSize + ';" href="' + settings.privacyPolicyUri + '">' + settings.privacyPolicyLinkText + '</a>.';
        html += '<div id="epdnotick" style="color:#ca0000;display:none;margin:2px;"><span style="background:#cecece;padding:2px;">' + settings.explicitCheckboxLabel + '</span></div>'
        html += '<div style="margin-top:5px;';
        if (settings.inlineAction) {
            html += 'display:inline-block;margin-left:5px';
        }
```

implementig class & ID of the following html link code

```
<a class="js-open-modal ctn" href="#" data-modal-id="popup1">Website Privacy Policy</a>
```

to call a third jquery script that open a pop up.

Tried to `.addClass()` and `$('#element').attr('id');` but nothing working.

This the third jquery script code:

```
$(function(){

var appendthis =  ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");

$('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$("body").append(appendthis);
$(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
//$(".js-modalbox").fadeIn(500);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#'+modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you define a new div with link and  use that div there ?

```
$("#id"), $("element") or $(".class")
```

after this

```
$("#foo").append("<div>hello world</div>")
```

is this work ?

Comment: TRIED TO SUBSTITUTE                                            settings.privacyPolicyUri                                                                             WITH                                                                                                $(function(){ var appendthis =  ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>"); $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
$("body").append(appendthis);$(".modaloverlay").fadeTo(500,0.7);//$(".js-modalbox").fadeIn(500);var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');$('#'+modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());});  });

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are mixing in so many different context that it is hard to get a grasp of what's going on let alone spot a typo or exactly where the code is failing. I see that you are concatenating everything into your html variable then adding text, an anchor tag, inline styles, and more html tags. It's mixing means you have to be careful with the placement of single and double quotes, colons and semicolons, equal, and plus signs. It would beat better to construct your html wrapping and assign it to a variable and then append CSS, attributes, and additional HTML.

Comment: Using jQuery append, css, and prop variables accordingly.